# Is Conditional Expectation of stochastic process a martingale?

Tags: conditional-expectation, martingales, filtrations

I have the following:

Let $Y$ be an integrable and $F_T$ -measurable random variable. Define $\{X_t\}_{t \in [0,T]}$ by $X_t =E(Y|F_t), \ \forall t \in T$. The $\{F_t\}_{t \in [0,T]}$ should be the filtration generated by $Y$ (or $X$?). Show that $\{X_t\}_{t \in [0,T]}$ is a martingale.

Can please someone help me? I can show the property of $E(X_t|F_s)=X_s$ for $s \leq t$ and that $X_t$ in in $L^1$ but I have troubles in showing that $X_t$ is adapted to the filtration since $Y$ is only $F_T$-measurable.

Comment: By the very definition of conditional expectation, $\mathbb{E}(Y \mid \mathcal{F})$ is $\mathcal{F}$-measurable for any $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{F}$...that's all you need to show that $X_t$ is $\mathcal{F}_t$-measurable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a full answer to the question in the title:

---

The conditional expectation of a stochastic process is a martingale if the following conditions are satisfied :

1. $X_t$ is $\mathcal{F}_t$-adapted.
2. $\forall t \geq 0$, $X_t$ is integrable.
3. $\forall t \geq s \geq 0, \operatorname{E}[X_t \mid \mathcal{F}_s]= X_s$ a.s.

---

Let's note $\forall 0 \leq t \leq T, X_{t} =\operatorname{E}[Y_{T} \mid \mathcal{F}_{t}]$

For the first condition, as @saz's comment says, by the definition of the conditional expectation, $\operatorname{E}[Y_T \mid \mathcal{F}_t]$  is $\mathcal{F}_t$-adapted for any $t$.

For the second condition, we have to show that $\operatorname{E}[\vert \operatorname{E}[Y_{T} \mid \mathcal{F}_{t}] \vert]<+\infty$, which is the case because $\mathcal{F}_{t}$ is a filtration generated by a random variable on a finite time and $Y$ only has finite values.

The third condition can be proven with the law of total expectations:

Let $(\Omega,\mathcal{F}_t,\operatorname{P})$ be a probability space, $\mathcal{F}_t$ being the filtration generated by $Y_t$. For a random variable $Y_t$ on such a space, the law of total expectations states that if $\operatorname{E}[Y_t]$ is defined (e.g. $\operatorname{E}[\vert Y_t \vert]<+\infty$), and with $s \leq t \leq T$, we have:

$\operatorname{E}[ \operatorname{E}[Y_T \mid \mathcal{F}_t] \mid \mathcal{F}_s] = \operatorname{E}[Y_T \mid \mathcal{F}_s]$

Which is the same as:

$\operatorname{E}[X_t \mid \mathcal{F}_s] = X_s$, and we then have the 3rd condition.

In short, the answer to the question in the title is **yes** in most cases that you will encounter in exercises or job interviews because they are almost always designed to be solved.